# How would I plot the metric $ds^2 =−(\phi^2 t^2)dt^2+dx^2+dy^2$ in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting

I've tried using:

```
ϕ = 1.9381 10^-14;
spaceRange = 5;
timeRange = 15000000;
ContourPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2 - ϕ^2 t^4 == 0, {x, -spaceRange, 
  spaceRange}, {y, -spaceRange, spaceRange}, {t, -timeRange, 
  timeRange}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotRange -> {{-spaceRange, spaceRange}, {-spaceRange, 
    spaceRange}, {0, 15000000}}]
```

But I'm not absolutely sure I've captured the nature of the metric with this contour.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: possible duplicate by OP: [Is it possible to take the square root of this metric?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/179898/34893).

Comment: As I've said to you two times already, the contour plot you are using has nothing to do with your metric. $t^2$ is not the same thing as $\mathrm dt^2$, and $\vec r^2$ is not the same thing as $\mathrm d\vec r^2$. You take the metric $\sim -t^2\mathrm dt^2+\mathrm d\vec r^2$, and then plot the level-sets of $-t^4+\vec r^2$. Why? These two objects are not the same; in fact, **they have nothing to do with each other**. I don't know what your intention is, but why do you post questions if you are going to categorically ignore the responses you get?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform See my post below. The OP is not completely wrong with plotting this as a light cone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
dt = {1, 0, 0};
dx = {0, 1, 0};
dy = {0, 0, 1};
Quiet[dim = 3;
  xx = Table[x[[i]], {i, 1, dim}];
  uu = Table[u[[i]], {i, 1, dim}];
  (*define the Lorentz metric (using ϕ=1)*)
  g[x_] = -x[[1]]^2 TensorProduct[dt, dt] + TensorProduct[dx, dx] + TensorProduct[dy, dy];
  Dg[x_] = D[g[xx], {xx, 1}];
  ginv[x_] = Inverse[g[xx]];
  (*compute Christoffel symbols by Koszul formula (needed for geodesic equation)*)
  Block[{e = IdentityMatrix[dim]}, Γ[x_] = 
    Table[Sum[
      1/2 (e[[k]].ginv[xx].e[[l]]) Plus[
        +e[[j]].(e[[k]].Dg[xx]).e[[i]], 
        -e[[i]].(e[[j]].Dg[xx]).e[[k]], 
        +e[[i]].(e[[k]].Dg[xx]).e[[j]]
        ], 
      {k, 1, dim}], {i,1, dim}, {j, 1, dim}, {l, 1, dim}]
      ];
  (*solve geodesic equation symbolically (will only work for very simple metric g;
  NDSolve may help in the general case)*)
  γ[τ_] = 
   Table[y[i][τ], {i, 1, dim}];
  geodesic[x_, u_] = DSolveValue[
    Join[
     Thread[γ''[τ] + (Γ[γ[τ]].γ'[τ]).γ'[τ] == 0],
     Thread[γ'[0] == Evaluate[uu]],
     Thread[γ[0] == Evaluate[xx]]
     ],
    Table[y[i][τ], {i, 1, dim}],
    τ
    ];

  (*covariant derivative in operator form; in cov[X,Y], 
  vector field Y is derived in direction of vector field X*)
  cov[X_, Y_] := x \[Function] Evaluate[D[X[xx], {xx, 1}].Y[xx] + (Γ[xx].Y[xx]).X[xx]];

  (*Riemann curvature in operator form*)
  riem[X_, Y_, Z_] := With[{
     LieXY = x \[Function] Evaluate[D[Y[xx], {xx, 1}].X[xx] - D[X[xx], {xx, 1}].Y[xx]]
     },
    x \[Function] Evaluate[cov[X, cov[Y, Z]][xx] - cov[Y, cov[X, Z]][xx] - cov[LieXY, Z][xx]]
    ];

  (*generate Riemann curvature tensor by testing operator form with coordinate vector fields*)      
  e = Table[x \[Function] Evaluate[IdentityMatrix[dim][[i]]], {i, 1, dim}];
  R = x \[Function] Evaluate[Table[
       riem[e[[i]], e[[j]], e[[k]]][xx].g[xx].e[[l]][xx],
       {i, 1, dim}, {j, 1, dim}, {k, 1, dim}, {l, 1, dim}
       ] // Simplify];
  ];

(* routine for plotting the infinitesimal light cone at point {t,x,y}*)
infinitesimallightcone[{t_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}] := 
  ParametricPlot3D[
   Evaluate[
    Block[{v, w},
     {t, x, y} + s {1, v Cos[ϕ], w Sin[ϕ]}/Sqrt[{1, v Cos[ϕ], w Sin[ϕ]}.{1, v Cos[ϕ], w Sin[ϕ]}]  
       /. Solve[({1, v, 0}).g[{t, x, y}].({1, v, 0}) == 0, v][[1]] 
       /. Solve[({1, 0, w}).g[{t, x, y}].({1, 0, w}) == 0, w][[1]]
     ]
    ],
   {s, -r, r}, {ϕ, -Pi, Pi},
   Mesh -> None,
   PlotStyle -> Directive[ColorData[97][2], Opacity[0.6], Specularity[White, 30]],
   Lighting -> "Neutral"
   ];
```

Plotting a light-like geodesic that emanates the origin (actually, geodesics starting from there are not well-defined), some infinitesimal light cones along its path (in yellow), and the one-sided (truncated) light cone at `{0,0,0}` (which actually is also not well-defined).

```
t00 = 3/2;
r = 1/20;
p[τ_] = Simplify[geodesic[{t00, 0, 0}, {-1, t00, 0}], 0 < τ < t00/2];
p[τ_] = p[τ] - p[t00/2];
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[{p[τ][[1]], p[τ][[2]] Cos[ϕ], p[τ][[2]] Sin[ϕ]}],
  {τ, 0, t00/2}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[ColorData[97][1], Opacity[0.6], Specularity[White, 30]],
  BoundaryStyle -> Black,
  PlotPoints -> {200, 72},
  Lighting -> "Neutral"
  ],
 infinitesimallightcone@*p /@ Subdivide[0, t00/2, 20],
 Lighting -> "Neutral",
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
 AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", "y"}
 ]
```

[image]

This looks quite similar to the OP's plot. And actually, we have

```
p[τ][[2]]^2 + p[τ][[3]]^2 - 1/4 p[τ][[1]]^4 // Simplify
```

> 0

So, yes, OP's plot appears to be essentially correct (up to the factor `1/4` somewhere).

PS.: I tried to implement also the Riemannian curvature tensor. Apparently, it is equal to `0`, so that the metric `g` is flat everywhere:

```
Max[Abs[R[xx]]]
```

That's no miracle because the metric `g` is obtained via pull-back of the (flat) Minkowski metric along the mapping

```
Quiet[Φ[x_] = {1/2 x[[1]]^2, x[[2]], x[[3]]}];
```

which can be checked as follows:

```
DΦ[x_] = D[Φ[xx], {xx, 1}];
DΦ[xx]\[Transpose].DiagonalMatrix[{-1, 1, 1}].DΦ[xx] == g[xx]
```

> True

This mapping is a diffeomorphism from $]0,\infty[ \times \mathbb{R}^2{$ to $]0,\infty[ \times \mathbb{R}^2{$, and thus.

Comment: Very nice (upvote). But is the use of `XX` instead of `X` on rhs of `Dg` and `ginv` intentional?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Daniel! Yes, that's intended. `XX` evaluates to `{X[[1]],X[[2]],X[[3]]}`, so that the expressions can indeed be evaluated and simplified. That's also the reason for the `Quiet`: Mathematica complains otherwise about indexing into a undefined symbol. I prefer this approach over using `{t,x,y}` everywhere because it is easier to port to higher dimensions (just redefine `dim` and `g`; the computational parts should remain the same (untested)).

Comment: That makes the produced code also easy to compile, which I do very often for numeric simulations (admittedly, rather for Riemannian manifolds than for Lorentzian ones).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher - This looks awesome and it will take me a little while to digest everything that you've done here.  Using this metric, is a function available that will tell me the travel distance of a photon given the travel time?  (This metric expands quadratically, so the photon will move through expanding space, like man walking against the direction of a moving sidewalk).

Comment: If you give me a formula for the distance travelled, I can try to show you how to implement it. I used to be a Riemannian geometer; I learnt only a tiny bit of Lorentzian geometry and most of that has already diffused out of my head.

Comment: Could you please confirm that your plot (the large curved cone) represents a set of all possible photon trajectories from the origin, but not the borders of the space? And also that this metric describes a spacetime whose spatial part at any moment of time is an infinite flat Euclidean plane? The OP is trying to build a model of a closed universe expanding with the acceleration and may need help visualizing this space. The universe with this metric is not closed, although the space beyond the cone horizon is causally disconnected from the origin (if no superluminal "inflation" there). +1

Comment: The distance traveled by a photon in this space is given by $r=\dfrac{\phi}{2}(t-t_o)^2$ there $t$ is the current age of the universe from the origin and $t_o$ is the age of the universe at the moment of the emission of the photon while $dr^2\equiv dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$ (you can drop the third coordinate in this case). See this for details: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/423897/how-can-i-trace-the-path-of-a-photon-on-space-time-defined-by-this-metric/423906#423906

Comment: @safesphere I am not sure what you mean. What I can confirm is that this metric is flat (globally, in all directions). I also showed above that this spacetime is isometric to an open halfspace in flat Minkoswki space. So all computations can also be done in Minkowski space. Should be simpler there.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much! It is just for the OP to be clear that this is not a closed space (e.g. not a expanding sphere).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher - It's going to take me a while to digest your code.  This is some pretty advanced stuff.  In the mean time, to make sure we're dealing with the same metric, given $\phi$ in the original post, what do you calculate for the age of the universe when it will expand faster than the speed of light?

Comment: @DonaldAirey I don't understand your question, in particular what you mean by "age of universe". And why should that be relevant to ensure that we use the same metric? Up to the $\varphi$, the metric is the same. Btw., the diffeomorphism that scales the time axis by a suitable factor (maybe $1/\sqrt{\varphi}$) pulls your metric back to mine, so all qualitative statements that hold for one metric hold also for the other. And as I have already demonstrated, you could work equally well on the $t>0$ halfspace of standard Minkoswki space.

Comment: I skipped the constant $\varphi$ because it is pretty close to `$MachineEpsilon`; since plotting functions in Mathematica use merely machine precision, such a small number has the potential to do a lot harm to the plots. The output would have to be scaled anyways.  Also, please notice that this is a Q&A site about the software Mathematica, not on physics.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher - I had posted a response to the issue of machine precision, but I admit I don't understand all the operations going on.  It could be that you're adding 1.0 so $\phi$ at some point, which would explain why you used unity units.  Again, I have some follow up questions related to this space that are beyond the scope of this question. Connect with me through LinkedIn if you'd like to discuss further.

Comment: The main goal of this exercise was to allow me to calculate the space between two objects in this universe given the amount of time it takes a photon to travel from one point to the other.  I've posted a follow-up question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2900161/the-distance-between-two-points-in-a-hypothetical-universe , posted a bounty for it and would greatly appreciate the help.